# How to remove k__BackingField from response json?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-core, json.net

I try to remove k__BackingField from my json response.
I use Newtownsoft.Json and .net core 3.1.

Example is:

"k__BackingField": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",

```
"<Violations>k__BackingField": [
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {}
],
"<ResultType>k__BackingField": 5,
"<LockOwner>k__BackingField": null
}
```

So, data model class is:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
[Serializable]
public class DataModel
{
    // [JsonProperty("uid")]
    [DataMember]
    public string uid;

    // [JsonProperty("name")]
    [DataMember]
    public string name;

 /*etc fields*/
}
```

I try to use Serializable, try to remove it, but nothing happens.
If i remove  `MemberSerialization.OptIn` i have recursive error (my other fields).

So, how can i fix `k__`  ?

Thank you!

Comment: please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ... as for your `DataModel` which has only `uid` and `name` **FIELDS** (not properties) this should not happend as obviously `k__BackingField<..>` came from automatic properties

Comment: also `Serializable` attrubute looks suspiciously ... Shouldn't be a `DataContract` ? (this come from first google result ...)

Comment: `k__BackingField` is for automatically implemented properties, which **you don't have**; are you sure you don't have `[field: DataMember]` on a property like `public string ResultType {get;set;}` ? but: no, the code shown *will not* create that json - please can you show an object that *actually does* do this, ideally with the exact call you're making to Json.NET

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't using `MemberSerialization.Fields` and auto-properties? if so: *don't do that*?

Comment: @MarcGravell it's because `Serializable` attribute ... question is already asked ... first result for googling `k__BackingField json`

Comment: eesh, fair enough @Selvin (although I can't make it repro, but: sounds possible); tip for Admiral Land: the times when you need `[Serializable]` is *basically* zero.

Comment: I notice you have applied data contract member attributes `[DataMember]` to some properties.  Rather than using `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` have you tried applying a data contract attribute to your type: `[DataContract]`?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Well, you do need to replace `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` with `[DataContract]`; if you don't `DataModel` will serialize as an empty object, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/IWAREQ vs https://dotnetfiddle.net/yZReiB. But your question title isn't asking why `DataModel` serializes as empty, it's asking why some container type is serializing with backing field names.  But you don't show that type at all so we really can't answer.  Can you [edit] your question to clarify the problem, so that the written problem and the c# code are consistent?

Answer (score 3):

It *sounds* like you're actually using `MemberSerialization.Fields`, i.e.

```cs
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]
public class DataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

with

```cs
var obj = new DataModel { Name = "abc" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

which results in:

```
{"<Name>k__BackingField":"abc"}
```

in which case, either *don't do this* (just remove the `MemberSerialization.Fields`) - this works fine:

```cs
public class DataModel
{
    // optional: [JsonProperty("name")] to change "Name": to "name":
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which gives:

```
{"Name":"abc"}
```

(or "name" with the optional bit)

or if you *must* use fields: give them custom names:

```cs
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]
public class DataModel
{
    [field: JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which gives:

```
{"name":"abc"}
```